# I want to send password through email in php when I change my admin panel password

Tags: php, mysql

This is a php code from where i am updating my password. but when  i changed my password the mail is sent to my email id. but changed password is not sent. so please help me how to send changed password to my email id. thanks in advance

```
if (isset($_POST['update_p'])) {

  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];

  $uname = $_SESSION['username'];

  if($password != $cpassword){
    $msg2 = "Passwords do not match.";
    header("location:change_pw.php?msg2=$msg2");
    exit;
  }

  $sql = "UPDATE admin SET password = '$password' WHERE username = '$uname'";
  $query = $conn->query($sql) or die ('no table found');

   if($query){
          $msg3 = "PASSWORD CHANGED!!!<br> Login with your new password.";
          $query="select password from admin WHERE username ='seeknfameadmin'";
          $result   = $conn->query($query) or die ('no table found');
          mail('msharif849@gmail.com','seeknfame',$result);
          header("location:login.php?msg3=$msg3");
  }

}
```

Comment: because in your result only 1 or any number showing

Comment: You should never store passwords as plaintext.You could use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to encrypt the password. Your code is also open to SQL injections

Comment: `row=mysql_fetch_array($result); $pass=row['password'];` add code just before the mail function.

Comment: @JeesKDenny mysql_* functions are deprecated...

Comment: row=mysql_fetch_array($result); $pass=row['password']; after writing this in email function mail('msharif849@gmail.com','seeknfame',$result);      now is it ok?

Comment: go with mysqli @DarkBee

Comment: @ DarkBee thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

change in place of $result to $password

```
 mail('msharif849@gmail.com','seeknfame',$password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You are sending this

```
   mail('msharif849@gmail.com','seeknfame',$result);
```

where is your `password` . `$result` is 1 or true if query run

do this

```
$msg = "your new password is $password";

 mail('msharif849@gmail.com','seeknfame',$msg);
```

Comment: @MohsinSharif if it woked then mark it your answer :)

Comment: one thing more. how can i secure this code from mysql injection? pleas if you can help me

Comment: use pdo or mysqli bind param method to run queries. Refer these http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: i really appreciated it

Comment: there is a tick mark just below the anwer you have to click that

Answer (score 0):

This was my question:
**I want to send password through email in php when I change my admin panel password.**
and the exactly answer is:

$msg = "your new password is $password";

mail('msharif849@gmail.com','seeknfame',$msg);

thanks to all for contributing answers.